# Sinch pause outgoing audio or video

Tags: sinch

How can I pause the outgoing video, so that the person who receive it to stop seeing it until I will remove the pause option?

Same question related to audio call. How to make something like mute mic, so that the received audio is stop until I un-mute the mic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming in next beta release, not doable now

Comment: Perhaps you can add a reference or a timeline for that beta ?

Comment: Hey @cjensen are there news about this?